# Databinding ChildDataContext's Property not updating ChildView

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a TabControl which binds to a list of TabViewModels, each of these ViewModels represent the DataContext (ViewModel) for a View which gets placed inside the TabControl.

My MainView holds a ComboBox with the following Bindings:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding CurrentTabViewModel}"
DisplayMemberPath="SetNr"
SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSet}"
ItemsSource="{Binding AllSets}"
SelectedIndex="0">
```

My MainViewModel initializes the list and makes the tabs show up in the view.
The CurrentTabViewModel is a SetViewModel which contains this and some extra stuff:

```
Public Class SetViewModel
        Implements IPageViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Property CurrentSet() As Set Implements IPageViewModel.CurrentSet
            Get
                Return _currentSet
            End Get
            Set(value As SetEntity)
                If Not _currentSet Is value Then
                    _currentSet = value
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSet")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements 

INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

        Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
        End Sub
End Class
```

With the IPageViewModel looking like this:

```
Public Interface IPageViewModel
        ReadOnly Property Name As String

        Property CurrentSet() As SetEntity
    End Interface
```

My SetView with the content has the following Bindings, it's DataContext is the 
SetViewModel:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentSet}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Set}" />
```

I have a DataTemplate for the View's content

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Set" DataType="{x:Type entity:SetEntity}" />
```

The entity contains some fields I represent in the view which is just a bunch of Controls 
with some Data Binding for their content. the Database connection works and the AllSets 
are retrieved from the Database correctly.

The problem is that when I change the selected item in my ComboBox, it updates the 
Property on my SetViewModel and it fires the OnPropertyChanged event, but the view doesn't 
update. It stays empty. I have already tried putting a label in the MainView with the following XAML:

```
<Label DataContext="{Binding CurrentTabViewModel}"
Content="{Binding CurrentSet.SetNr}" />
```

The above XAML does respond to the changing of the CurrentSet view. It looks as though the 
SetView doesn't respond/receive the property change.

Comment: *Each of the TabViewModels are a View*... arghhhhh!!! Please remove that MVVM tag, as you clearly have no idea what that is! View models are supposed supply the data and functionality that each view requires, *not* supply the views themselves. I suggest that you go and read some more MVVM tutorials *before* you ask any more questions here, as this website is not here to teach users MVVM.

Comment: @Sheridan After reading your comment I noticed I made a mistake in writing the first paragraph. I have edited the question regarding this mistake

Comment: Good, I'm glad that was just a typing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have defined a DataContext in my SetView to have Design Time data and AutoCompletion:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <model:SetViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

It seemed the View instantiated it's DataContext in favor of that defined by the MainWindow, which led to nothing being displayed and the SetView only talking to it's instance of the SetViewModel.

After removing that line everything went as expected and the data was properly being updated.